# Displaying current date using extjs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

I need to display current date using ExtJs with rails, on header's toolbar. Is there any way to display it on Display Field without using DatePicker?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
new Ext.form.DisplayField({
  html: new Date().format('Y-m-d')
});
```

Comment: In my ui.js file i wrote this :`{
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            value:  new Date().format('m/d/Y'),
                            id: 'cur_date'
                        }`